# How do I format a pandas dataframe string value to date?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have following string value obtained from a pandas dataframe.

```
u'1:19 AM Eastern, Tuesday, May 16, 2017'
```

How do I convert it to a datetime.datetime(2017,5,16) object?

Thx.

Comment: Don't think you can, this format is extremely hard to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a custom date parser, to give you some ideas here's a reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd 
import datetime 
from StringIO import StringIO 

st = u'01:19 AM Eastern, Tuesday, May 16, 2017'

def parse_date(date_string):
    date_string = ",".join(date_string.split(',')[-2:]).strip()
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%B %d, %Y')

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(st), header=None, sep="|", date_parser=parse_date, parse_dates=[0])
```

If you print the dataFrame content as follows, :

```
print("dataframe content")
print(df)
```

you will get this output:

```
 dataframe content
            0
 0 2017-05-16
```

checking the dtypes confirms that the column is now of type datetime:

```
print("dataframe types")
print(df.dtypes)
```

output:

```
dataframe types
0    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you so much for a thorough explanation of how I can use this solution.